# how to download files from links?

Tags: php, download, web-crawler

i search for links from a website with this code.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// search the results from the starting site
if( $result ){
   preg_match_all('/<a href="(http:\/\/www.[^0-9]+.pdf?)"/', $result, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER );
     foreach($output as $item  ){ 
        print_r($item );
      }
}
copy($item, 'file.pdf');
?>
```

just one pdf links that read. then i need a code to download pdf files that provide by links in php. copy function doesn't work. 
thank you :)

Comment: Not sure I get your question right. You want all the found pdf's to be sent to the browser as downloads?

Comment: @Oldskool i wanna download all pdf files from links in a web and save them in my folder in computer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've solved it, using this code, thank you for @Oldskool :) :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url='example.com';
//set your save path here
$path = '/home/igos/pdfs/';

$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
     $link= $e->href;
     if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $link)) {
          $result[] = $link;
          copy($link, $path . basename($link));
     }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. You are only printing inside your foreach loop, not saving anything.
2. You are using the `copy()` function with the static filename `file.pdf`.

You will probably want to save all the files within your foreach loop and with either the same name or something random (otherwise, each save operation would overwrite the previous `file.pdf`), something like this:

```
// Set your save path here
$path = '/home/igos/pdfs/';

foreach($output as $item){ 
    copy($item, $path . basename($item));
  }
```

That would save all the files, keeping their original filename to the `/home/igos/pdfs/` folder.

Comment: i've tried it, and the browser give warning : basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @igos You will have to use the variable that holds the actual filename (which should be visible from the `print_r($item)` output). It's probably something like `$item[0]`.

Comment: will you help me step by step? first, i need to crawl links with pdf extension. i make new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187865/find-link-in-pdf-extension]